# How to take a photo with OpenCV at a higher resolution than the video resolution on a usb camera?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

i got an usb cam that support "live mode" aka video and "snapshot mode".
The max resolution for snapshot mode is 4128 X 3096.

```
import cv2

from cv2 import CAP_DSHOW


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,CAP_DSHOW)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 4128)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 3096)

ret,frame = cap.read()

while(True):
    cv2.imshow('img1',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('y'):
    cv2.imwrite("c10.png",frame)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
break

cap.release()
```

[Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSAoe.png)

I tried every resolutions higher than full HD but i cannot get an image with a resolution higher than 1920*1080px.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:  Does anyone know a simple way to grab a frame from a USB camera at a desired resolution in python ? I tried a pygame example but only got a black image even if my camera is detected at [0].

Comment: Your doc mentions 1020x1080 as the max resolution for video (live mode). Only single frame capture (snapshot) supports the higher resolution. I believe capturing using `cv2.VideoCapture` is done in the live mode.

Comment: Can you try a directshow tool like GraphStudioNext?  If you are able to tune the parameters in some nodes there then you could try to hack that to the opencv directshow class (videoinput library).

Comment: Thank you @wohlstad, i guessed the same thing but was still hoping it would work at higher res just for one frame.

Comment: Thank you @Micka, i will look into that if i don't find another easier solution.

Comment: Does anyone know a simple way to grab a frame from a USB camera at a desired resolution in python ? I tried a pygame example but only got a black image even if my camera is detected at [0].

Comment: Does anyone know how to take a simple photo from the command line in Windows without Python? If so, you can use a Python `subprocess()` to call that.

Comment: @NZ-999 try graphstudioNext anyways. If there is any way to access your camera in that snapshot mode with directshow then you can do it in GraphStudioNext and then you will basically know HOW you can access that camera in that mode (on a direct show parameter level). If you dont use GraphStudioNext (or another raw directshow application) you will never know whether only your used libs are too limited or whether the drivers (or the device) dont allow you to use that mode at all. Do you have ANY application that runs the snapshot mode of the cam?